# 'unicode' object has no attribute 'prettify'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, prettify

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse an html article. I use some functions to clear the html, so I can keep only the main article.

Also, I want to save the Soup Output to a file. The error I get is the following:

```
soup = soup.prettify("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'prettify'
```

Source Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk
import argparse

def cleaner():
    url = "https://www.ceid.upatras.gr/en/announcements/job-offers/full-stack-web-developer-papergo"
    ourUrl  = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl)

    #remove scripts
    for script in soup.find_all('script'):
        script.extract()
    soup = soup.find("div", class_="clearfix")

    #below code will delete tags except /br
    soup = soup.encode('utf-8')
    soup = soup.replace('<br/>' , '^')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(soup)
    soup = (soup.get_text())
    soup=soup.replace('^' , '<br/>')

    print soup
    with open('out.txt','w',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        f.write(soup.prettify())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cleaner()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `soup` is not a `BeautifulSoup` or `Tag` instance anymore after these lines:

```
soup = (soup.get_text())
soup = soup.replace('^' , '<br/>')
```

It becomes a unicode string which, of course, does not have a `.prettify()` method.

Depending on what your desired output is, you should be able to make use of `.get_text()`, [`.replace_with()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with), [`.unwrap()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap), [`.extract()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) and other `BeautifulSoup` methods to clean up your HTML instead of trying to deal with it as a regular string.